# Passing Primitive data types by reference in JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am an embedded C programmer and was integrating my code written in native C/C++ with Java using JNI. I was curios to know whether pass by reference for primitive data_type be possible? I am refering this link http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#5279  which doesnt help my cause.

Basically what i want to achieve is something like this :
// Get the val updated by the native call
int nativeFunc(short val);
Java Function :

```
class main
{
   short val;
   val = 0;
   nativeFunc(val);
   System.out.println(val)
}

int nativeFunc(short val)
{
   // Code to update OUt param val
   // Need this portion
}
```

I dont know if its very trivial question with a very easy answer.

Comment: It would be somuseful to have instance's variable name quering for such thing >< I lack this future so much....

Answer (score 3):

Java is always pass-by-value. For a discussion, see [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

You could either *return* the modified primitive from the function, or change it to take *an object* holding the primitive.